# kAudioUnitType_MusicEffect as AVAudioUnit

Tags: midi, audiounit, coremidi, avaudioengine

I'd like to use my `kAudioUnitType_MusicEffect` AU in an `AVAudioEngine` graph. So I try to call:

```
[AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument instantiateWithComponentDescription:desc options:kAudioComponentInstantiation_LoadInProcess completionHandler:
```

but that just yeilds a normal `AVAudioUnit`, so the midi selectors (like -`[AVAudioUnit sendMIDIEvent:data1:data2:]:`) are unrecognized. It seems `AVAudioUnitMIDIInstrument instantiateWithComponentDescription` only works with `kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice`.

Any way to do this? (Note: OS X 10.11)

Answer (score 0):

Make a subclass and call instantiateWithComponentDescription from its init.

Gory details and github project in this [blog post](http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/multi-timbral-avaudiounitmidiinstrument/#avfoundation)

http://www.rockhoppertech.com/blog/multi-timbral-avaudiounitmidiinstrument/#avfoundation

This uses Swift and kAudioUnitSubType_MIDISynth but you can see how to do it.

Comment: I don't see how subclassing will help. I still have to call `instantiateWithComponentDescription` which doesn't work for `kAudioUnitType_MusicEffect`. If I switch it to `kAudioUnitType_MusicDevice` then I get an assertion failure when trying to connect the audio input.

Answer (score 0):

This works. It's a subclass. You add it to the engine and you route the signal through it.

```
class MyAVAudioUnitDistortionEffect: AVAudioUnitEffect {

override init() {
    var description                   = AudioComponentDescription()
    description.componentType         = kAudioUnitType_Effect
    description.componentSubType      = kAudioUnitSubType_Distortion
    description.componentManufacturer = kAudioUnitManufacturer_Apple
    description.componentFlags        = 0
    description.componentFlagsMask    = 0
    super.init(audioComponentDescription: description)
}

func setFinalMix(finalMix:Float) {

    let status = AudioUnitSetParameter(
        self.audioUnit,
        AudioUnitPropertyID(kDistortionParam_FinalMix),
        AudioUnitScope(kAudioUnitScope_Global),
        0,
        finalMix,
        0)

    if status != noErr {
        print("error \(status)")
    }
}
```